# Restatable numbering works only for theorems

Tags: numbering

I have the below code, that uses restatable. The restated theorem gets the correct numbering, which is, the numbering of the original statement. However, the restated proposition gets the wrong numbering.

I've tried using 'newtheorem' after 'usepackage', but without success (didn't compile).

When using

```
   \newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
```

instead (commented out line below), it works, but it is not the numbering I'd like to have.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

```
\documentclass[conference,9pts]{IEEEtran}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{thm}[theorem]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{defn}[theorem]{Definition}

\newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Proposition}
%\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]

\newtheorem{lem}[theorem]{Lemma}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{thm-restate}

\begin{document}

\section{Main}

\begin{defn}
Define something
\end{defn}

\begin{lem}
1+1=2
\end{lem}

\begin{thm} 
1+2=3
\end{thm}

\begin{example}
4
\end{example}

\begin{restatable}{prop}{myProp}
1+4=5
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}{theorem}{myThm}
1+5=6
\end{restatable}

\section{Restate}
\myProp*
\myThm*
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me if I use the correct order of packages and declarations.

```
\documentclass[conference,9pts]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{thm-restate}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{example}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}

\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]


\begin{document}

\section{Main}

\begin{defn}
Define something
\end{defn}

\begin{lem}
1+1=2
\end{lem}

\begin{thm}
1+2=3
\end{thm}

\begin{example}
4
\end{example}

\begin{restatable}{prop}{myProp}
1+4=5
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}{thm}{myThm}
1+5=6
\end{restatable}

\section{Restate}
\myProp*
\myThm*
\end{document}
```

I see no need to define `theorem` and `thm`, but it's not really relevant.

[image]